# Daily spread measure for products in crypto exchanges?

Tags: historical-data, cryptocurrency, liquidity

I'm now trying to trade in crypto, and I want to get a measure of the liquidity of products listed in exchange.

- Trading volume is a good measure, and easy to obtain.
- Spread is also a good measure, but how can I measure it in a daily basis (i.e., aggregate)

How can I do it?

---

My thoughts:

I came across a paper: https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/30/12/4437/4047344. but it seems a bit too complex?

Comment: Arbitrage spread across various exchanges might be a helpful metric as well.